# Akka REST service + dispatch

Tags: scala, rest, akka, databinder, scala-dispatch

I followed the example [here](https://github.com/buka/akka-mist-sample). It works, fine. But now I need to perform some business logic in `case get:Get =>`

Required business logic includes using [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) library. In a nutshell, I do a request to some page, get the data, wrap it in some class, and return it.

My receiving case looks like this:

```
case get:Get => {
  get.response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  val response = Sender.doLogin
  val battery = (response.batteryRemaining / response.batteryCapacity) * 100
  val soc = (response.pluginState + ", " + response.chargingStatus).replaceAll("_", " ")
  val jsonResult = pretty(render(("battery" -> battery) ~ ("soc" -> soc)))
  get OK jsonResult
  // get OK "works"
}
```

This does not work:

```
ERROR [akka:event-driven:dispatcher:event:handler-5] akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler - 
    [akka.http.Servlet30ContextMethodFactory$$anon$2]
    [org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException]
    [org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.setError(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:295)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(Mist.scala:346)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(Mist.scala:343)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$class.rawComplete(Mist.scala:357)
    at akka.http.Get.rawComplete(Mist.scala:407)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$class.complete(Mist.scala:343)
    at akka.http.Get.complete(Mist.scala:407)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$class.complete(Mist.scala:340)
    at akka.http.Get.complete(Mist.scala:407)
    at akka.http.RequestMethod$class.OK(Mist.scala:388)
    at akka.http.Get.OK(Mist.scala:407)
    at com.thenewmotion.caronline.services.rest.BatteryStatusService$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(BatteryStatusService.scala:36)
    at com.thenewmotion.caronline.services.rest.BatteryStatusService$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(BatteryStatusService.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:563)
    at com.thenewmotion.caronline.services.rest.BatteryStatusService.apply(BatteryStatusService.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.invoke(ActorRef.scala:890)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageInvocation.invoke(MessageHandling.scala:25)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutableMailbox$class.processMailbox(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:214)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher$$anon$4.processMailbox(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:120)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutableMailbox$class.run(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:186)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher$$anon$4.run(ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThread.run(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:181)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:97)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:271)
    ... 25 more
]
```

It also seems, that it starts making the request (with dispatch library) **after** it responds with `HTTP 200 OK`.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: For whatever it is worth, your use case seems to be exactly the kind of stuff that [Blue Eyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes) was made for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning off connection-close: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/config/akka-reference.conf#L262

Comment: Did not help. I also verified, that effectively any dispatch request from the receive body results in this exception.

Comment: That's interesting. When I leave it without requests for about 10 minutes, it works once, and then stops working again.

Comment: What happens if you set the  get.response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
just prior to the get OK ?

Comment: Same thing. But I was able to make it work by increasing some timeouts in `akka.conf`. Namely, `actor.timeout` and `http.timeout`. And I also added a `get.timeout(10000)` to the beginning of the `case` expression.